# import psd as text into illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, svg

I have a psd file with picture and text, that I am trying to convert to svg - so the text will be scaleable.  I am working with cs5.  I believe you can export as svg from photoshop-cc now, but I dont have access to that.

When I open my psd in illustrator, selecting the convert layers to object option - the text is imported as an image.

I can copy each text box from fireworks and paste into illustrator, but if I select more than one text box it is pasted as an image.

Is there a way to open psd in illustrator (5) keeping the text layers as text?

Comment: Try saving the PSD as a PDF with Acrobat 7 compatibility and "Preserve Photoshop Editing Capabilities" checked. Then open the resulting PDF with Illustrator. Does that work?

Comment: yes.  But it seems to import as an image and not as text.  When i then save it as a svg it saves as a mess.  And the file is massive as it is not text but images.  But It looks a lot better than I was working with.

Answer (score 1):

If you've done anything to the text, such as apply layer styles or you've made it raster, you won't be able to import your text.

The best option would be to recreate it in illustrator. Photoshop is not designed to produce SVG's, and SVG's shouldn't contain images.

Comment: SVG *can* contain images.

Comment: You're right, they can contain images, i'm saying they _shouldn't_. Optimisation and file size come into play.

Comment: That's fair enough, but it's worth pointing that out because there are plenty of situations when you could perfectly reasonably use images in SVG.

Comment: True, I've seen a few examples of using PNGs within an SVG and really pushing what can be done with mediaqueries inside it. But in response to the original question, photoshop + SVG haven't quite married yet :/